# Generate PDF from HTML using pdfMake in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdfmake

I am trying to create a `PDF` from my HTML using `pdfMake` and `Angular` (I've also tried `jsPDF` and couldn't get it to work either).  I tried using the following code in my Angular controller:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML])
var docDefinition = {
    content: [blob]
}
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

but I receive the following error:

> Unrecognized document structure: {"_margin":null}".

My HTML consists of two simple tables in a div `exportable`.

If anyone knows a solution to this issue, or another way to get the HTML into a PDF from Angular, PLEASE help.

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out.

1. You will need [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/%22pdfmake%22).  You do NOT need to do any injection in your app.js to either, just include in your script tags
2. On the div that you want to create the PDF of, add an ID name like below:

   ```
    <div id="exportthis">
   ```
3. In your Angular controller use the id of the div in your call to html2canvas:
4. change the canvas to an image using toDataURL()
5. Then in your docDefinition for pdfmake assign the image to the content.
6. The completed code in your controller will look like this:

   ```
          html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
               onrendered: function (canvas) {
                   var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                   var docDefinition = {
                       content: [{
                           image: data,
                           width: 500,
                       }]
                   };
                   pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
               }
           });
   ```

I hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!

Comment: How do we can add some additional content in pdf file using same library? Any idea?

Comment: Can this create multiple pages if image is large?

Comment: Yes, you will probably have to play with it a little.

Comment: This should **not** go into a controller since you're accessing the DOM.

Comment: What if we are trying to print an entire view, which includes the view of many child views. You know a view with directives inside pointing to other controllers an views. Would this also keep the integrity of the web page, including the css that is not present in the view.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you try it.  If you look at the pdfMake documentation, they give examples of how to do paging.  You will probably have to do one section at a time with a forEach or something.

Comment: note that html2Canvas is in very experimental stage. The author does not suggest to use in production environment.

Comment: When I do that, I don't get the whole element. Instead, I get neighbouring elements + parts of the element I want.

Comment: Must have something to do with your divs.  I'd need to see your code.

Comment: Hey, it works fine for me, but "-webkit-mask-box-image" won't show up correctly at the pdf output :(

Comment: This doesn't work if document is larger than one page.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I'm getting this error `Uncaught (in promise): invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya  - unfortunately, I do not know anything about node.js.  Sorry.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff It worked but still there is a problem, pdf only generates one page, and that cuts rest of the content, do you know how to add pages dynamically?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff do you how to add pdf page, if content is more than one page?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya - I have never tried it, but I kept the following link in case I ever needed it.  Hope it helps you!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731494/pdfmake-how-to-create-multiple-page-pdf-with-different-orientation

Comment: Do i need to include any script tags?

Comment: Yes, you do need script tags as stated above.

Comment: I know its may be to late, but do you have a Plunker for this?

Comment: @DenisK - sorry, I don't, but I'll try to help you if you are having an issue.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff - thank you, really kind. actually i found myself good with the pdfmake library, it fits perfect for my needs

Comment: can anyone give one example on this?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff thanks for posting your solution. A question: does your approach deal with the data breaking over pages (I can't see how it can btw)?

Comment: I tried this exact code in Ionic Framework Angular Typescript however this isn't working. Is there any specific code that I need to add in here? Thanks

Comment: @Rich - unfortunately I don't know anything about Ionic Framework or Angular Typescript.  This was done in an asp.net MVC project using AngularJs.

Comment: I'm so happy you wrote this! I was under the impression PdfMake could only export PDFs with a template, and not through the DOM. Saved me a lot of headache

Answer (score 33):

I know its not relevant to this post but might help others converting HTML to PDF on client side. This is a simple solution if you use kendo. It also preserves the css (most of the cases).

```js
var generatePDF = function() {
  kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#formConfirmation")).then(function(group) {
    kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Converted PDF.pdf");
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="generatePDF()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save as PDF</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="formConfirmation">

    <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
      <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Theme example</h1>
        <p>This is a template showcasing the optional theme stylesheet included in Bootstrap. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique by building on or modifying it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Buttons</h1>
      </div>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-link">Link</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Link</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link">Link</button>
      </p>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Tables</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Thumbnails</h1>
      </div>
      <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="A generic square placeholder image with a white border around it, making it resemble a photograph taken with an old instant camera">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Labels</h1>
      </div>
      <h1>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </h1>
      <h2>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </h2>
      <h3>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </h3>
      <h4>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </h4>
      <h5>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </h5>
      <h6>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </h6>
      <p>
        <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
        <span class="label label-success">Success</span>
        <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
        <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </p>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Badges</h1>
      </div>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Inbox <span class="badge">42</span></a>
      </p>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">42</span></a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge">3</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Dropdown menus</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown theme-dropdown clearfix">
        <a id="dropdownMenu1" href="#" class="sr-only dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Navs</h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Navbars</h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Alerts</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <strong>Heads up!</strong> This alert needs your attention, but it's not super important.
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Progress bars</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"><span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%"><span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%"><span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%"><span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%"><span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%"><span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%"><span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 20%"><span class="sr-only">20% Complete (warning)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 10%"><span class="sr-only">10% Complete (danger)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>List groups</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
              Cras justo odio
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Panels</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what about scroll, if there were data is to much of long, then pdf should be export like that isn't that right?, i have tried it and up voted it, but in my case there is scroll-able data in my div, can you please add scroll-able true here? i have tried a lot.

Comment: @Jigar7521 as far as I've seen in kendo pdf export, there are limitations. Like if your div is hidden it will give you a blank pdf. There is a work around as suggested in kendo, here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#off-screen-content. So if you have a scroll-able element workaround is create a div with style="position: absolute;width: 800px;left: -10000px;top: 0;" and pan everything whichever way you want to export in pdf. 

Or use kendo grid with scrollable->virtual and it has option to export pdf with all data in the grid.

Comment: @Mahib What about svg elements like nvd3 charts? because its not display in pdf.

Comment: @dkc007 I don't have any clue about svg elements. There are limitations on Kendo, please check their official limitations guide.

Comment: @dkc007 you can check the following link in kendo for svg.. I'm not sure if it works or not but you can play around with it.. 

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom

Comment: Known limitations >> http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#known-limitations

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: It's easy and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I use this way - maybe it will be useful for someone

```
     import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
     import htmlToPdfmake from 'html-to-pdfmake';
        
          saveReport() {
          //Learning the html code of the table
            let pdfTable = document.querySelector('#tableDataVM').innerHTML;
            var html = htmlToPdfmake(pdfTable);
            pdfMake.createPdf({
              info: {
                title: "Disposal Report",
                author:'mikka',
                subject:'Theme',
                    keywords:'Report'
              },
              footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
                return {
                  margin: 10,
                  columns: [
                    {
                      fontSize: 9,
                      text: [
                        {
                          text: 'Page ' + currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount,
                        }
                      ],
                      alignment: 'center'
                    }
                  ]
                };
              },
              content: [
                {
                  text: "Disposal report for the period " + this.lastPeriod + " by average\n\n",
                  style: 'header',
                  alignment: 'center',
                  fontSize: 14
                },
                {
                  text:
                    "Param1: " + this.dataTableReport.host + " (" + this.dataTableReport.hostdescription + ")\n" +
                    "Param2: " + this.dataTableReport.claster + " (" + this.dataTableReport.clasterdescription + ")\n" +
                    "Param3: " + this.dataTableReport.pull + " (" + this.dataTableReport.pulldescription + ")\n",
                  fontSize: 10,
                  margin: [0, 0, 0, 20],
                  alignment: 'left'
                },
                html
              ],
              pageOrientation: 'landscape'//'portrait'
            }).open();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what it worked for me
I'm using html2pdf from an Angular2 app, so I made a reference to this function in the controller

```
var html2pdf = (function(html2canvas, jsPDF) {
```

declared in html2pdf.js.

So I added just after the import declarations in my angular-controller this declaration:

```
declare function html2pdf(html2canvas, jsPDF): any;
```

then, from a method of my angular controller I'm calling this function:

```
generate_pdf(){
    this.someService.loadContent().subscribe(
      pdfContent => {
        html2pdf(pdfContent, {
          margin:       1,
          filename:     'myfile.pdf',
          image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
          html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
          jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can you please show me your angular2 component code?

Comment: the code is there, do you have any link to your github or something so that to check it out

Comment: this is the `component.ts` code which I'm using for generating pdf https://gist.github.com/NikhilRadadiya/a5812171aac5497aa3134a3aaa1a8f4a

Comment: you need the equivalent of this stuff declare function html2pdf(html2canvas, jsPDF): any;

Answer (score 0):

was implemented that in service-now platform. No need to use other library - makepdf have all you need!

that my html part (include preloder gif):

```
   <div class="pdf-preview" ng-init="generatePDF(true)">
    <object data="{{c.content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width:58vh;height:88vh;" ng-if="c.content" ></object>
    <div ng-if="!c.content">
      <img src="https://support.lenovo.com/esv4/images/loading.gif" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is client script (js part)

```
$scope.generatePDF = function (preview) {
    docDefinition = {} //you rootine to generate pdf content
    //...
    if (preview) {
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getDataUrl(function(dataURL) {
            c.content = dataURL;
        });
    }
}
```

So on page load I fire init function that generate pdf content and if required preview (set as true) result will be assigned to c.content variable. On html side object will be not shown until c.content will got a value, so that will show loading gif.