# Ng-table export to pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf, ngtable

I know that stackoverflow has questions related to ngTable and how to export it to pdf. However, It did not worked for me any of the answers related to it, because one of the main problems is that most of the solutions uses html2canvas, for example this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs). The problem is that html2canvas only "screenshots" what is rendered on html, and because my table has many data, it has pagination and, because of that, the only thing that is exported to pdf is the first page.

**Question**: Does anyone has successfully exported an ng-table with pagination to pdf? How did you do that?