# EXCEL and PDF creator in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, excel, pdf

How to create and download Formatted EXCEL and PDF document in Angularjs 1 using angular / java script . I have come up with many possible solution but non of them provide formatting otherwise i have to create the document on server and then download it.

Comment: Try this https://codepen.io/marco27384/pen/pboLyx to generate and download excel sheet.
You can try alasql, ngCSV plugins but they don't support formatting.

Comment: This is useful for pdf generator:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs