# How I do paginate with Pdfmake and html2canvas?

Tags: angularjs, html2canvas, pdfmake

I created a html table using angularjs. I am able to download the document as pdf using pdfmake and html2canvas based on this question:

[Generate PDF from HTML using pdfMake in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs)

The document layout is nice and everything works fine until it comes to documents that goes beyond a single page. In that case the pdfmake generates a blank (2 pages) pdf document.

How can I handle the generation of a multipage document with pdfmake and html2canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the problem. When the image generated by html2canvas is larger than one page it seems that pdfmaker is unable to handle the page split. So you have to managed output context by yourself.

Comment: If we take 2 different div how to show them in different pages..?