# How Can I generate a PDF doc from a react component (JSX)?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, components

I have a react component that is contained in a tab. How Can I generate a PDF doc from that specific react component (JSX) when clicking a button ?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having? You say 'in a tab', what do you mean? Can you show us a skeletal code example of what you want converted to PDF? We need more info mate

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/) and the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs), which, while relating to AngularJS, gives you an idea of how to use flat JS to generate a PDF from a webpage. You'll be creating the PDF from the actual generated DOM content, rather than JSX.