# convert angular view to static html

Tags: angularjs, pdf, directive, html-to-pdf

I hvae an angular view of a pdf preview that utilizes a controller to fill the view in.  I am using pdflayer then to convert the html page into a pdf.  The problem however is that no matter how I try and do this the scope variable values never make it into the pdf. I am basically trying to figure out a way to capture the angular view as an html string (data already injected) so that I can pass it to pdflayer.  I have tried creating a directive and used replace within the directive then collecting the DOM as a string using .HTML().

For example:

I could like this

```
<div id="name">{{test.name}}</div>
```

to become this

```
<div id="name">Bob Smith</div>
```

It inevitably however turns into this when i use $('#name').html() and then console log it

```
<div id="name"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="name">{{test.name}}</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated even if the solution is to use a different method to create the pdf.  Ultimately, I need to get a angular view into a formated pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below library would work for you : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-save-html-to-pdf

Comment: Thanks Vijay.  I checked that out a few days ago and based on the [demos](http://hearsid.github.io/angular-html-to-pdf-save/demo/index.html) from the page it doesn't look like it produces very high quality pdfs.  If this is not the case let me know however I need something that will look good both on screen and in print

Comment: I saw another question on SO and posting the link here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162901/6347317  .I also created a plunker with @Rani Radcliff's solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/TZQvTOPxj10pSTTSNRFI?p=preview   . "pdfmake" is a popular library and there may be more options in their webpage to style the content further. Please check it out.