# How to create Pdf using Spring and Angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, pdf-generation

I want to create a PDF file so that when I click on a button `SaveToPDF` it should fulfill the requirement. But I'm unable to do it, any help on how to achieve this using `RestEndCall` through back-end using `SpringMVC` and for front-end using `Angular4/5/6/7/8+`

Also, what data should I be sending to back-end? And to be precise, I don't want to create each cell by cell. If there is any other option to create a PDF which look exactly like the web page.

Comment: can you able to add more information about your question

Comment: by using pd4ml and itext pdf you can convert HTML page into pdf or you can make your own pdf

Comment: do you mean, you want to save the current web page as pdf?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs

Comment: have you considered using Puppeteer from Google?
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/?authuser=3&hl=vi

Comment: If I make my own pdf, I wont make same like the web page right.?? the css styles they have used in the web page will be missing.

Comment: yes @BhushanUniyal. I have web page where few details are displayed.. lets say, when you open bank statement and when you click on save to pdf , the same web page is converting to PDF right.. that kind of stuff I need.

Comment: @user3132347 i have mentioned piece of code which will help you to achieve this, you need to modify the given code and trigger event during  save pdf option

Comment: please prvide some more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve it in the frontend, no need to backed request.
Here is angular example:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {
     $scope.data=  [{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Safi","statutImp":"operationnel"}];

     $scope.export = function(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
            }
        });
     }
   }
 ]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="listController">
    <div id="exportthis">
      download me as a pdf
    </div>
    <button ng-click="export()">export</button>
  </div>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You ask about how to create a Page screenshot in a PDF format.

In practice, client-side libraries for making pdf are very limited by functionality and produce poor result,

Whats left is server-side rendering.

I had success with [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-from-the-trenches/tree/master/create-pdfs-with-wkhtmltopdf) a long time ago, there are some other alternatives.

You can start your implementation journey by searching `wkhtmltopdf` or `PhantomJS` alternatives for Java.

How should this work? Headless browsers open a URL and wait for a window.variable, when `true` script (same wkhtmltopdf for example) makes the job. There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/1181479) with a list of headless browsers. Best PDF solutions will be based on any of them.

Comment: This really is the best answer, we are currently using wkhtmltopdf and while it doesn't always get the conversion perfectly, it really is the best we have found.