# AngularJS pdfMake with html2canvas is not defined at b.$scope.export error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdfmake

I don't know why is it like that. In the tutorial that I follow it says I don't need to inject anything to my app.js

any ideas?

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs) link

here's the code of my function

```
$scope.export = function() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('balanceSheet'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
            }
        });
    }
```

the scripts that I imported came [here](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted)

- pdfmake.min.js
- vfs_fonts.js

html2calvas, pdfMake, and onrendered shows they have an error

see image of it 
[image: Code]

do I need to inject something or what?

by the way this is a single page application

Comment: can you show your scripts (html code), or/and specify the versions of used libraries?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey  pdfmake v0.1.36