# Creating PDF from HTML UI not as an image

Tags: angular, jspdf

I want to create a PDF out of HTML (What we are seeing in the screen) but NOT as Image. Image is working fine but doing the same for HTML, it is not capturing as in UI rather it is been different.

I am using jsPdf, html2canvas and Angular 5

Please let me know how to capture the HTML(as seen in UI) to PDF (not as Image).

Thanks
vinod.

Comment: I have also used Bootstrap CSS for the UI

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript

Comment: This should help you. This question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs

Comment: Hi Abishet, i am able to do with Image but my requirement is PDF should be text so that we can search the text.

Comment: Hi Abishek & Kunal, i am able to do in Image and Text is not appearing as seen in UI. Do you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I use the native browser [print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) function combined with a print stylesheet such as the one provided from bootstrap or you can write your own.

Just call this inside your method

`print()`

The print dialog will open and you can choose the Destination **Save as PDF**  instead of choosing a printer.

Also make sure that the **Background graphics** is enabled also in the **More Settings** section.

Comment: Hi, i am able to create an pdf out of image, but we need as a text so that  is searchable.