# Download a dynamic html page as pdf on button click

Tags: python, django, html2pdf, pdfmake

I want to download pdf where the source is a url or a div.

I have a database of quizzes based on different categories. These quizzes have MCQ and images. I am able to render the quiz in an HTML however I want to give users a chance to download the quiz on each topic as pdf using "click here to download"

On clicking a pdf with the questions and images will be downloaded. I tried using

```
pdfMake
```

using the following code

```
$("#download_quiz").click(function(){
  
    // create the window before the callback
    
      // pass the "win" argument
      var docDefinition={
        content:[
            "hello world"
        ]        
      }
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
   
  
});
```

however, my content is dynamic. How do I achieve it ? Is there another way to do this. I am using Django as my webdev.

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: No Error message. I want to know what should be used in place of "Content" to render my html content? The syntax if possible or some example.

Comment: It seems that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs) can help you with it's syntax as well as steps to implement.